# I want to generate outliers in binary logistic model

Tags: r, logistic, outliers, binary-data

I want to generate outliers in binary logistic model

What I want is:
to select 3 elements  of 10 elements  that are randomly generated, and:
if the selected value is 1  convert it to zero
&
if the selected value is 0  convert it to 1
and display the new y with 10 elements including the changed and the unchanged values

I searched through r and I  was able to write the following code to generate y-outliers:

```
Y <- as.numeric(runif(10)>0.5)
Y[toreplace] <- sample(y = seq_along(Y), size = 3)
Y[sample(Y, 3)] <- 1
```

but this code displays only the 3 changed elements,  besides it change 0  to 1 only; I want to change both: from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0.

I also want correct code to change x-values in logistic regression to to obtain good leverage points and bad leverage points

any help, please

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with your last, more statistical question -- to make an influential point, you need its x-value to be many standard deviations from its mean.

It's not clear to me that there's any sense in which the replaced values in your question are any more outlying than the ones they replace. To make the values *outlying* you probably want to have the probability of getting a 1 change with some predictor, $x$; then flipping points where the local values are nearly all of one kind could be regarded as introducing an outlier.

[image]

However, use `sample` to choose the 3 points to replace and note that `1-Y[replace]` will be 0 when `Y[replace]` is 1 and vice versa.

Comment: In the logistic regression model, outliers push the fitted $\hat{\beta}$ towards 0. This is clear from your picture, but it has been proven formally.